# Read xml file, modify the values/add elements/attributes and save the xml how?

Tags: javascript, xml

Using javascript, I want to read xml file from the disk, modify the values/add elements/attributes and save the xml back to disk.

Anyone knows here can i find examples that works with IE and Firefox? I allready find examples to read, now changing values that's the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to read and write to disk from the browser and not node.js,
the first step is to use an `input` tag of type `file` to get access to the file system.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="input" accept="text/xml">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

As soon as a file is selected we want to extract the blob from the element.
A good moment to do that is during the change event.

```
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const file = input.files.item(0);
});
```

There is more than one way to parse the blob into a tree of elements.
Here I took advantage of the fact that the browser parses xml documents in HTTP requests.

```
function blobToDocument(blob, callback) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('Get', url);
  request.responseType = 'document';
  request.addEventListener('load', () => {
    callback(request.response);
  });
  request.send();
}
```

After the blob has been parsed we can manipulate it like we would manipulate the DOM tree.

```
function editDocument(document) {
  const element = document.createElement('editor');
  element.textContent = 'JavaScript';
  document.firstChild.appendChild(element);
  return document;
}
```

In order to save the file to disk we need to reverse the process of parsing,
converting the tree of elements back to a string.

```
function documentToString(document) {
  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  return serializer.serializeToString(document);
}
```

The only thing left is to send the file back to disk.
To achieve this we can trigger a click event on a link with our modified file.

```
function download(string, mime) {
  const blob = new Blob([string], { type: mime });
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'document.xml';
  a.click();
}
```

Here is the complete code

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const file = input.files.item(0);
  blobToDocument(file, (xmlDocument) => {
    editDocument(xmlDocument);
    download(documentToString(xmlDocument), "text/xml");
  });
});

function blobToDocument(blob, callback) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('Get', url);
  request.responseType = 'document';
  request.addEventListener('load', () => {
    callback(request.response);
  });
  request.send();
}

function editDocument(document) {
  const element = document.createElement('editor');
  element.textContent = 'JavaScript';
  document.firstChild.appendChild(element);
  return document;
}

function documentToString(document) {
  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  return serializer.serializeToString(document);
}

function download(string, mime) {
  const blob = new Blob([string], { type: mime });
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'document.xml';
  a.click();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="input" accept="text/xml">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```